# Glorot initialization and gradient variance condition

Tags: neural-networks

In the Glorot initialization I don't understand why this condition should be validate to avoid
vanishing/exploding gradient problem:

> we need the gradients to have equal variance before and after flowing through a layer in the reverse direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gradually smaller or larger variance means smaller or larger magnitudes, which is indeed the problem of vanishing or exploding gradients respectively.